# Idea/ heuristic behind linearisation theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, chaos-theory, jacobian

Define $\vec{F}$ to be a mapfrom the state space to the tangent space

Without formally defining what the linearisation theorem is, the idea behind this theorem is that for any fixed point $x=x^{*}$, the behaviour of the neighbourhood about this fixed point is equivalent to the linear system
$\dot{y}=Ay$ for a square matrix A and vector y.

The behaviour about the neighbourhood of a fixed point $x=x^{*}$ can be determined by evaluating the Jacobian 
$d\vec{F}\left ( x^{*} \right )=\frac{\partial f_{i}}{\partial x_{j}} \mid_{x=x^{*}}$ 
of the vector field $\vec{F}\left ( x \right )$ at the fixed point $x=x^{*}$.
However, a change of coordinate z=Py is required so that an equivalent system $\dot{z}=Jz$ where J is the block diagonal matrix, P is a matrix and z is a vector.

It is not explained in my notes why this change of coordinates is required. 
Under what circumstances would $\dot{z}=Jz$ be more appropriate than the linear system $\dot{y}=Ay$?
Good explanation is needed and will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Centering by $x=x^*+y$ indeed yields $\dot y=Ay$ with $A=d\vec F(x^*)$. Next, diagonalizing $A$ as $A=P^{-1}JP$ with $J$ diagonal (strange notations, but...), one gets $P\dot y=JPy$, that is, $\dot z=Jz$ with $z=Py$. Any mystery remaining?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand what your question is.

The change of coordinates $z=Py$ is only needed if you want to put the linear system $\dot{y}=Ay$ into the form $\dot{z}=J{z}$ where $J$ is the Jordan normal form of $A$. If $A$ is diagonalizable, then $J$ will be a diagonal matrix.

This is not required but it is useful as it allows for the solution $y(t)$ to be written in the form

$$y(t)=Pe^{Jt}P^{-1} y \ (t_0)$$

where $e^{\cdot}$ is the matrix exponential.

Comment: Because it seemed that OP was confused about why one would diagonalize after linearizing, so I wanted to help clarify when one would do so. I did it as an answer because I cannot comment.

Comment: Understandable!  Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Are there any circumstances where we would want to put the linear system $\dot{y}=Ay$ into the form $\dot{z}=Jz$?

Comment: The main reason why you would do this is because diagonalizing the system tells you a lot of information about the system: A) It allows you to write down the solution. B) The entries in the diagonal matrix $J$ tell you what the eigenvalues of the system are. C) The columns of $P$ tell you the eigenvectors of the system. You can think of $P$ as a change of coordinates that aligns the n-axes along the $n$ eigenvalues of the system.